# Get Google Meet attendee Status

Tags: javascript, java, google-calendar-api, google-meet

I am trying to find the status of google meet conference participants. I want to know who connects, who leaves the meeting, all in realtime. Is this possible?

I went through the API documentation but I am not seeing how this can be done:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

Unfortunately, the requested information is currently not available to any public API.

#### Feature request:

There's a feature request related to this in Issue Tracker:

- [Meet - real time API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157261118)

I'd suggest you to click the [star the issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to help prioritize this and to keep track of its development.